# How to extract phone number from the 'Call' link in mobile Google local search results?

Tags: html, css, selenium-webdriver, xhtml, webdriver

When a search for e.g. "chiropractors+New York+NY" is performed with a mobile User Agent, Google returns a page that looks something like:

[image]

I'm looking to extract (programmatically with WebDriver (Python) by XPath, CSS selector, or ID) the phone number that is linked to from the Call link to the right. I've tried using Firebug & developer tools, but all they tell me is the the text 'Call' of this link. I've even clicked on the link, brought up Skype, copied the displayed number, and searched for it in the source, but not match. Can this even be done? The full HTML source can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/D6NhrDg1).

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this in Java... you didn't specify a language

```
List<WebElement> results = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[data-akp-oq]"));
for (WebElement result : results)
{
    System.out.println("Business name: " + result.getAttribute("data-akp-oq"));
    System.out.println("Phone number: " + result.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-url]")).getAttribute("data-url"));
}
```